# How to load Linux PC to make it warm?

Tags: testing, temperature

I have erratic working linux box and I suspect that it have some issues with either thermal monitoring modules, or even hardware.

I think about logging for some time temperature other things to see what's wrong.
However I have no idea how to load pc without running X server (easier to relaunch or stop, less things that can go wrong).

Is there any ideas for custom script for loading up pc, (i.e. what built-in utilities could load up pc (xz, gzip similar resource heavy operations)) or there exists any kind benchmarks that could load up pc. I just need load nothing more. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

Try out:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom | bzip2 -9 >> /dev/null
```

or use [stress](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/), a tool specifically designed to impose load on and stress test systems. It will launch multiple, parallel jobs and occupy 100% of your CPU:

```
stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s
```